# Name rows by serial number

Tags: hive

I have TableA -

```
NRow
----
   1
   2
 ...
1000000
```

And TableB -

```
RowCount  Name
--------------
     100    A
      10    B
     200    C
     ...   ...
```

I want to add a tag to TableA, which will take value "A" for first 100 rows, "B" for next 10 rows, "C" for next 200 rows and so on. Can Hive do this?

Comment: the best way is to use udf.

Comment: How do I automatically do it even with an UDF?

Comment: Consider write a function that starts with loading the table B data, and then process the Table A data, output the name value. If you are asking how to automatically add a UDF to hive like the original ones.What i use is hive.semantic.analyzer.hook configration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question - it is possible via a cross join.

```
select a.*, b.Name
from tablea a,
(select RowCount, sum(RowCount) rows over (order by Name) as CumRow from tableb) b
where a.NRow between b.CumRow-b.RowCount+1 and b.CumRow
```

An UDF can also do it - but it will have to effectively simulate the cross join (because it will need to carry entire information of TableB and scan through TableA).